# Interface Builder is missing in xCode 4.0

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have installed xCode 4.0.2 on my mac mini, every thing is working fine, I have compiled some sample applications too, but the interface builder is missing in the directory Developer/Application while xCode.app is there.

Comment: You must be new to xCode 4. xCode 4 has Interface Builder and code editor in the same program. (p.s. xCode 5 will release soon, are you ready?)

Comment: yes I am new to xCode 4, I have now found it. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interface Builder is no longer a sperate app, it is fully integrated in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 4):

Interface Builder is inbuilt with Xcode 4 now. So you can just select your .xib file and it will show at right side. You may need to select last icon on right side top navigator to display Interface builder.